# How to click on the webelement with in the highlighted script using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@value='Sign Out']")))
```

but no luck.. please see image for the html script

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `click()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[action*='Logoff']>li>input[value='Sign Out']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `submit()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action, 'Logoff')]/li/input[@value='Sign Out']"))).submit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks DebajanB, tried using XPATH and it worked. There's typo "form", after that it's cool. again thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Nick Corrected the typo.